# Python Pandas - Combining merge and filter in a single step

Tags: python, sql, pandas

In the following piece of code:

```py
df_emp11 = pd.read_table("C...PyCharm2018.3/config/scratches/dataset3",  engine="python", sep = ',', usecols = ['EmpID','Name','Salary'])
df_emp12 = pd.read_table("...PyCharm2018.3/config/scratches/dataset4",  engine="python" , sep = ',',usecols = ['EmpID','Name','Salary'])
df = pd.merge(df_emp11, df_emp12, on=['EmpID'] , how='outer', indicator=True)
df = df[df.Salary_x !=df.Salary_y]
```

Instead of using `pd.merge` in a step and the filtering out the records in the last step, is there a way to write SQL like query like:

```sql
Select * from df_emp11 left join df_emp12 
on df_emp11.Name = df_emp12.Name
where df_emp11.Salary != df_emp12.Salary
```

I am trying to make it memory efficient!!

Sample data: set1:

```
EmpID,Name,Salary
123,Allan,8890
234,Thomas,9990
345,Bill,7789
445,Bill,9980
```

Set2:

```
EmpID,Name,Salary
123,Allan,8890
234,Thomas,9990
345,Bill,778
```

Expected output:

```
EmpID Name_x  Salary_x Name_y  Salary_y    
345   Bill      7789   Bill     778.0      
445   Bill      9980    NaN       NaN
```

Comment: could u share an example dataframe with ur expected output?i guess you could refactor the code and intersect. an example would be nice though

Comment: you could look at `isin` but it seems like you need the join step first? hard to say without seeing a sample of your data.

Comment: added sample data and expected output

Comment: the `where` clause in the sql query will get executed after `left_join`, which is same as doing it in that order in pandas, first join it, then filter the result.

Answer (score 1):

The query looks fine except for the column you used to join the tables.
In pandas, you used `EmpID` as key to merge, but your query used the `Name` column. So query should be something like this (i did not test this though):

```
SELECT df_emp11.EmpID, df_emp11.Name, df_emp11.Salary, df_emp12.Name, df_emp12.Salary
FROM df_emp11
LEFT JOIN df_emp12
ON df_emp11.EmpID = df_emp12.EmpID
WHERE df_emp11.Salary != df_emp12.Salary
```

Also, i have no idea what SQL engine you're using. If you happen to use `PostgreSQL`, then you'd have to quote column names containing uppercase characters. E.g. `df_emp11.EmpID` => `df_emp12."EmpID"`